# Dynamic pivot with nulls using count() and CTE when columns are unknown

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am soo close!
I have a survey and the client wants to be able to see reports using various weights for the answers. SQLFiddle only allows 2008 and up but in 2005 I am getting these results:

```
Lesson wt count -> | w1_5 | w2 | w3 | w5_5 | w6_5 | N
-----------------------------------------------------
q2                 | 1.5  | 2  | 3  | 5.5  | 6.5  | 9
```

Obviously they should be counts and not weights.

Furthermore the only record being returned happens to be a row that has 0 nulls.

I have made an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d106/15/0) with a non-dynamic example of my expected outcome at the bottom.

I am not sure what the difference is that is making my dynamic query not sum and the non-dynamic one does.

Here is my previous work ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404062/sql-server-advanced-report-of-multiple-rows-into-one),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459355/sql-server-2005-fill-pivot-table-with-0s),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465666/sql-server-2005-percentage-in-parenthesis-in-pivot-table))

**---UPDATE---FINAL SOLUTION---**

Posted [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d106/35/0)
For those who are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dynamic sql inner joins each derived table, and you use one derived table for each weight. Some weights do not exist, so the result is empty result set. If you replace inner with left join, you will see your data, but the weight values, not the counts. To be honest, I don't understand why are you doing the joins in the first place. Why don't you generate a pivot query which would resemble pivot example you displayed at the bottom of the fiddle?

So, replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT -- Weight as the alias for join uniqueness
    @join_List = @join_List + ' 
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT lessonid, weight, count(weight) AS weightcnt 
        FROM tblResultsChoices 
        GROUP BY lessonid,weight
    ) w' + REPLACE(weight,'.','_') + ' 
ON (w' + REPLACE(weight,'.','_') + '.lessonid = weight_count.lessonid AND w' + REPLACE(weight,'.','_') + '.weight = ' + weight + '' +')'
    ,@select_List = @select_List + 
        ',isnull(w' + REPLACE(weight,'.','_') + '.weightcnt , 0) as w' + REPLACE(weight,'.','_') + ''
    ,@pivot_List = COALESCE(@pivot_List + ',', '') + '[' + weight + ']'
FROM Weights
```

Oh, about Sql Fiddle: if I understood what I was told, you are supposed to delimit each sentence with semicolon if you want it in same batch. Didn't try it yet, though.

**UPDATE:** been playing around a bit more. You are generating `select w1.weight` where it should read `w1.weightcnt`. As you can see in code snippet above, replace `.weight` in @select_list part with `.weightcnt` and it will work. One question still remains: why aren't you building the same pivot query as working example?

Comment: yeah that pivot query was much more simple. That is what I am doing now. I had been using the more complex one for another query and didn't realize the added complexity I was causing for myself.

Comment: I'm glad we ended on the same page. It is easy to astray when code starts to pile up. Good luck with your project.